# syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: errors

I don't know how to use this, I'm trying to fix the codes, but I can't fix this one. Someone could please help me?

```
public $is_success = true;
    public $messages = (
        'success' => [],
        'error' => [],
        'admin_error' => [],
    );
```

The line with error is the 'success' => []. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `=>` is the array assignment operator, and you haven't told PHP this is an array. Try:

```
 public $is_success = true;
 public $messages = array(
        'success' => [],
        'error' => [],
        'admin_error' => [],
    );
```

### References

- [Arrays in PHP](https://php.net/arrays)

Comment: Now come to this "fatal" error:

public static function is_form_submitted() {
  return Utils::is_ajax() && 'isset'( $_POST['action'] ) && 'elementor_pro_forms_send_form' === $_POST['action'];
 }